# assign responsible for something

Tags: usage

Is it correct to use ASSIGN like this?

> I was assigned responsible for the research.
>
> I was assigned a/the responsible person for the research.
>
> I was assigned a responsibility for the research.

Comment: I think the 2nd example should be, **I was assigned *as the/as a* responsible person for this research.**

Comment: The third one is the correct version (but with _the_ or no article). You assign a task _to_ a person.

Comment: Or *I was assigned **to be** responsible for the research*.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that you do see the use of _the responsible_ instead of the more usual _the person responsible_ but only by people who usually speak another language more than the y do English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct rendition would be:

> I was assigned responsibility for the research.

"Assigned" is the past participle of the verb *to assign*, meaning to be given a role or responsibility. It doesn't work with 'responsible' because that is an adjective, not a noun, so it cannot be the name of something you were given.

An exception might be if the adjective 'responsible' formed part of a compound noun for the role you were given, for example:

> I was designated **the responsible adult**.